# Can't find the difference why one code works and other shows runtime error for Question asked in Snackdown'19 codechef challenge?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Question [SPREAD2](https://www.codechef.com/SNCKQL19/problems/SPREAD2) asked in Snackdown'19 codechef challenge

> There are N people numbered 1 through N. Initially, only person 1
>   knows about Snackdown. On each day, everyone who already knows about
>   Snackdown tells other people about it. For each valid i, person i can
>   tell up to Ai people per day. People spread the information among the
>   people who don't know about Snackdown in the ascending order of their
>   indices; you may assume that no two people try to tell someone about
>   Snackdown at the same moment. Each person is only allowed to start
>   telling other people about Snackdown since the day after he/she gets
>   to know about it (person 1 can start telling other people already on
>   day 1). How many days does it take for all people to know about
>   Snackdown?
>
> **Input**: The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting
>   the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows. The
>   first line of each test case contains a single integer N. The second
>   line contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN.
>
> **Output**: For each test case, print a single line containing one integer — the
>   number of days.

One code for this question shows runtime error while the second one works perfectly fine. It is asked in the snackdown'19 qualifier round. As the contest is over so I want to clarify why [this code](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/20871155) shows runtime error

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t,s;
    int n;
    cin>>t;
    int count;
    while(t--) {
        count=0;
        cin>>n;
        int B[1000009];
        cin>>B[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {cin>>s;B[i]=B[i-1]+s;}
        for(int i=1;i<n;i+=B[i-1]) {
            count++;            
        }
        cout<<count<<'\n';
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

while doing it with while loop in [this code](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/20871904)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
int main() {
  int q;
  ll n;
  ll s;
  ll B[1000005];
  ll l,count;
  cin>>q;
  while(q--) {
    l=1;
    count=0;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>B[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
      cin>>s;
      B[i] = B[i-1]+s;
    }
    while(l<n) {
      count++;
      l+=B[l-1];
    }
    cout<<count<<"\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Appears to work correctly. Please help.

Comment: Please post code inside StackOverflow when possible, other sources could go offline or not be accessible by everyone (like in this case)

Comment: I have edited my post. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes, Both code works perfectly fine when tested by gdb. Also in my local g++ compiler, it is working fine. First code has for loop and the second one has while loop. Rest all code is same, yet codechef compiler runtime error in the first code.

Answer (score 1):

Both programs contain the line `cin >> n;` but the first one is using `operator>>(istream&, int&)` and the second one is using `operator>>(istream&, long long&)`.

This pattern repeats for all the stream extraction calls.

When the input doesn't fit in `int`, these two are going to behave very differently.

Comment: I have tested it by using long. While the constraint given in the question is 10^6 which can fit in int datatype.

Comment: @ShivamSahu: I checked the problem description in your question multiple times without finding a constraint.  Nothing useful shows up when I follow your link (maybe the site depends on Javascript?)  That's why it is important to put all relevant information in the StackOverflow post.

Comment: Constraints
1≤T≤1,000
2≤N≤10^5
the sum of N for all test cases does not exceed 10^6
0≤Ai≤N for each valid i
1≤A1..It is given after output.